# Angular material mini button around display some square

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Im using my `Angular 7` project for the [Angular material mini buttons](https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples) , I faced some issue  , I added angular mini button, its working but when I click the button showing some square, any one know how to fix that issue?

Thanks.

**please look at following  my issue**

[image]

**My code**

**component.html**

```
<div class="p-2">
<button mat-mini-fab>

            <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon " >edit
</mat-icon>
          </button>
</div>
          <div class="p-2"><button mat-mini-fab>

            <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">delete
</mat-icon>
          </button>
</div>
```

**.css**

```
.mat-mini-fab.mat-accent {
  background-color: #e9ecef;  color: black; box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
button{
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Is not it bad for accessibility?